Каким образом корректно выделять год, если он указан цифрами
В таком предложении:
"В следующем, 1998, году Николай поступил на службу".
Корректно ли выделять запятыми цифры?

не нужно выделять: в следующем 1998-ом году Николай поступил на службу.

Не, нужно так: В следующем, 1998 году, Николай поступил на службу. Пример из Сети; В следующем, 1998 году, вышло продолжение: "Гарри Поттер и Тайная комната".  Наращение не нужно: https://orfogrammka.ru/типографика/отсутствие_наращения_падежного_окончания/

@Sharon А зачем запятая после "году"? (тогда уж перед ним, как в вопросе...)   Пишем, как у Розенталя: Очередной, шестой том подписного издания на днях поступит в магазин; Он заговорил совсем другим, серьёзным тоном.

Правильно только у меня (обособление), красиво и разумно))  Обозначено уточнение. Нет уточнения? Тогда зачем "следующий"? Лишнее слово, где информативность текста? А без запятых только поздравление: Поздравляю всех с наступающим 2025 годом! // Шестой том – это другое, обозначение порядка при счете. А здесь – название года как периода времени, другая значимость. Имя собственное! Наверное))

@Sharon Вот именно, одно из двух определений года лишнее. Но если у вас уточнение, тогда слово "году" должно остаться в основном сообщении, а получается "В следующем Николай поступил на службу".

Ах! Я категорически против такого анализа,чтобы слова из предложения удалять.  Я понимаю так: Событие случилось в следующем году –  вот что важно для сюжета, именно это основная информация. А цифра – добавочное уточнение для ориентации читателя.  // Через запятую?  Справочник какой-то получается. Не художественно  и  неестественно. // Но вы бы дали свой ответ, может, он всем понравится.

@Sharon Как это? Всё, что можно удалить без ущерба структуры, оформляется парным знаком. Почему у вас слово "году" входит в уточнение?  // Отвечать на не очень корректный текст не хочется, поэтому пишу в комментариях.

А у меня так: В следующем (году), 1998 году, Николай...  Авторский речевой вариант, нестандартный, рекомендую) // Вы читаете с перечислением, как однородные члены. Но вы не можете записать естественную речь. // Конечно, вы скажете, что это пояснительные определения по Розенталю с уточняющим значением, только интонация от этого не изменится.

@Sharon  Вот, наконец-то ещё один плюсик в сторону согласия, спасибо!

Правила не должны быть "страшно далеки от народа"))
